# Getting Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class in magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento2.1

`enter code here`I have created a module for fetching data from table but when i run the module i am getting a fatal error saying **cannot re-declare class**. I have only one class called hello. This is my first time creating a module, i don't have experience in magento 1 [Link for module source code github](https://github.com/dkuser12/mag2.1.8/tree/master/Devchannel/Helloworld)

```
Block\Helloworld.php

    <?php
    namespace Devchannel\Helloworld\Block;


    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
    use Devchannel\Helloworld\Model\Data;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;


    class Hello extends Template
    {

        public function __construct(Context $context, Data $model)
        {
                    $this->model = $model;
            parent::__construct($context);

        }

        public function sayHello()
        {
            return __('Hello World');
        }
            public function getHelloCollection()
            {
                $helloCollection = $this->model->getCollection();
                return $helloCollection;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your class name to `Helloworld`. It should always match your filename.